# Migrating an XDV theme product to Diazo

Tags: plone, diazo, xdv

I am attempting to migrate from XDV to Diazo.

Currently I have a theme product that contains:

- a custom navigation.py and layout.py
- folders for:

  - overrides (for core overrides)
  - profiles (eg cssregistry.xml)
  - static (the theme resources, rules.xml, js, css and other cruft we may want to be able to call generically from the static directory with /++resource++theme/ syntax)
- unit tests in tests.py.

  **My question is:** does all of this come across to the Diazo theme or will i still need the current theme product installed for some parts of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think so, yes.

overrides/ and profiles/ are the same.

The registration in configure.zcml for the rules URL should change to a  one, and this will change the URL (++theme++ instead of ++resource++) but it's very similar.

There are some syntax changes, but they are minor and detailed here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.theming

Martin